# Reversing ArrayLists: Why must i equal half the size of the list?

Tags: java, arraylist

Earlier today my professor gave an in-class assignment of reversing an array without returning a new array and he expected (but didn't tell) us to do so without adding and appending elements. The solution I came up with is as follows:

```
ArrayList<Double> al = new ArrayList<Double>();
  al.add(5.00);
  al.add(1.00);
  al.add(4.00);
  al.add(2.00);
  al.add(3.00);
for (int i = al.size()-1; i >=0; i--)
{
   double temp = al.get(i);
   int zeroUp = ((al.size()-1)-i);

   al.set(zeroUp, temp);
}
System.out.println(al.toString());
```

Which `prints: [3.0, 2.0, 4.0, 2.0, 3.0].` I had noticed that it stops halfway each time, but I don't understand why. Set() doesn't remove the element whose value is to be sent over to the passed index, does it? I found on some random website that the correct answer is:

```
for (int i = al.size() / 2; i >=0; i--)
{                                   
   double temp = al.get(i);
   int zeroUp = ((al.size()-1)-i);
   al.set(i, al.get(zeroUp));
   al.set(zeroUp, temp);
}
System.out.println(al.toString());
```

> Output: [5.0, 1.0, 4.0, 2.0, 3.0]

Again, what is the reason why we have to divide `size()` by 2 and define a value for the element marked by me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're reversing the array *in place*. You're correct in thinking that `Set()` does not remove the element whose value is to be sent to the passed index.

So you have the array [5,1,4,2,3]. Once you get half way through your function, the array is [3,2,4,2,3]. Notice how the elements on both sides of the middle element are mirrors of each other. This means that when you try to set set the second half to the first half, the first half already equals the second half.

In other words, in order to reverse your array, you only need to swap the first half with the second half. [5,1,4,2,3] -> [3,1,4,2,5] -> [3,2,4,1,5]

I don't know if this is as clear as it could be, but I hope it helps

Comment: You're fast! Right after I posted this, I wrote the array down on a piece of paper and instantly noticed that I never "save" the overwritten value in any way. I'm genuinely frustrated that I didn't take notice of that while in class. 


I was sitting here holding my reply until I understood it. I completely understand now. Thank you!